# NextJS - request with large JSON object

Tags: reactjs, json, next.js, fetch

I do have a NextJS application where I make a request to the `api` route using `fetch`

```
      const options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(filesForImport),
      };
      const response = await fetch("api/import", options);
```

quite straightforward.

The catch here, is that the `body` is a "large" JSON object, with about 6500 lines (as per Postman).

This makes the request to completely hang, I don't see the `api/import` route to be called at all, and if I check the developer tools/Network I do see the request pending, and never resolves.

If I send a small json with 20 lines, all works as needed, so is defenetelly something with NextJS handling large JSON objects.

I did try to change the `config` for that route

```
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};
```

but it doesn't help.

For testing sake, the route doesn't do any logic, commented it all.

```
export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  console.log(99999)
  try {
    const files: LocalizationImportData[] = req.body;
    console.log(888, files)
    //await some logic here, which is commented
    res.status(200).end();
  } catch (err: unknown) {
    if (err instanceof Error) console.error(`failed to import records: ${err.stack}`);
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
};
```

in the case of small payloads, I do see the `99999` in the console, with large requests nothing happens.

I tried to make the requests via Postman, from Edge and Chrome browsers, all behave the same, the request just hangs forever.

The overall file size of that JSON payload is about 200kb, pretty small I'd say.

What else can be changed here?

Comment: after numerous tries, I established, any request under 16kb works ok, 1 byte more and it hangs. The app is inside a Docker container, wondering if it has a relation to this. NextJS: 12.3.2